# Python if elif else can't go to the elif statement Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, class, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

I have a piece of code that checks if there is an element that is displayed using p then it shows a dialog box but if it can't find it then it checks for another element and if that is displays another dialog box and if that element is not available, then it runs a piece of code.

The code is here.

```
if driver.find_element_by_class_name('error-code').is_displayed():
    LoginError.show()
elif driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sample-data-table"]/thead').is_displayed():
    QuestionUnavailable.show()
else:
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="radio1"]').is_displayed():
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="radio1"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-savecheck"]').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-alert-ok"]').click()
```

But when I run it, I get this error

```
File "Sciborg.py", line 60, in This
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".error-code"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can clearly see from the error, your code fails to locate element located by `error-code` class name.
This may be caused by several issues:

1. You are using a wrong locator, there is no element with `error-code` class name attribute on that page.
2. You are missing a wait / delay. Possibly you are trying to access this element before the page is loaded.
3. Maybe there is an iframe there so that element is inside that iframe so you have to switch to that iframe in order to access the desired element.
   **UPD**
   In case there is no such element on the page you can use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` method like the following:

```py
if driver.find_elements_by_class_name('error-code'):
    LoginError.show()
elif driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="sample-data-table"]/thead'):
    QuestionUnavailable.show()
else:
    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="radio1"]'):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="radio1"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-savecheck"]').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-alert-ok"]').click()
```

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('error-code')` will return a list of web elements. If element is existing this will return a non-empty list that is interpreted as a boolean `true`. Otherwise it will return an empty list that is interpreted as a boolean `false`.
Similarly I have updated the other `if` cases.
But you still should insure the elements you are trying to access directly are existing.
I mean these elements:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="radio1"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-savecheck"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-alert-ok"]').click()
```

Comment: But shouldn't it go straight to the elif statement

Comment: No, because it throws an exception that is breaking the program flow, it does not return a boolean `false` value.

Comment: ohhh ok thanks. Is there a way I can make it work?

Comment: Sure, there are several. I will update the answer

Comment: See the updated answer