# How I can solve this Selenium If Elif problem?

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, webdriver

I made a code to scrape some website. A list of IDs is iterated in the website, and it contains two conditions(If and Elif). But the problem is with the Elif. The error is it doesn't found the elif element (elem2).

I read in this question [Python if elif else can't go to the elif statement Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738037/python-if-elif-else-cant-go-to-the-elif-statement-selenium) the solution is a try/except, butI already used a Try/except to make works the if statement. What is a solution to make this code works with two conditions?

The code looks like this:

```
for item in list:
    input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "busquedaRucId")
    input.send_keys(item)
    time.sleep(2)

    elem1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'elem1')
    elem1_displayed = elem1.is_displayed()
    elem2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'elem2')
    elem2_displayed = elem2.is_displayed()

       try:
          if elem1_displayed is True:
             code to scrape given de first condition

          elif elem2_displayed is True:
             code to scrape given de second condition   

       except NoSuchElementException:
          input = driver.find_element(By.ID, ('busquedaRucId')).clear()
```

Than you for any help. I'm stuck with this problem for two weeks.

Comment: ``I read [...] the solution is a try/except`` - seems you read wrong? The solution was to use ``find_elements`` instead of ``find_element``

Comment: So the problem is that `elem2` does not exist?  That means `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'elem2')` is raising an exception.  You have the try/except in the wrong place.  An element not being _displayed_ is different than it not _existing_.

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your code by wrapping the `find_element` function in a function which handles `NoSuchElementException`s by returning `False`, basically making the error silent:

```py
def element_exists_and_displayed(driver, id):
    try:
        return driver.find_element(By.ID, id).is_displayed()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False

for item in list:
    input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "busquedaRucId")
    input.send_keys(item)
    time.sleep(2)

    if element_exists_and_displayed(driver, 'elem1'):
        # code to scrape given first condition
        pass
    elif element_exists_and_displayed(driver, 'elem2'):
        # code to scrape given second condition
        pass
    else:
        driver.find_element(By.ID, ('busquedaRucId')).clear()
```